# form submission with jquery

Tags: forms, submit

When submitting a form, I tried to submit the form by using the id and call submit on it by JQuery, but offcourse, the first script gets me in an infinite loop.

After using plupload, I noticed that they use another way to submit the form, which doesn't cause an infinite loop.

I tried to find information about this, but I cannot seem to get specific information about this?

```
$('#test').submit(function(e) {
   alert("here");
   $('#test').submit();
   return false;
});

$('form').submit(function(e) {
   alert("here");
   $('form')[0].submit();
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Begin edit

In first case you are triggering the jQuery submit event on your jQuery object (see http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

In second case, you are calling the javascript submit method on a javascript object. It does not trigger the submit event.

It is not the same 'submit' in both case.

In your second case, if you replace :

```
$('form')[0].submit();
```

with

```
$($('form')[0]).submit();
```

you will also end up with an infinite loop.

### End edit

in fact, with plupload, the point is waiting for the time when you will be able to successfully submit the form. The main feature is subscribing to StateChanged event.

It works this way :

1- first check if the queue is empty. If so, validate form submission(return true)

2- if the queue is not empty

a- startuploading remaining files
   b- subscribe to future 'StateChanged' events where it will check the queue. If it is empty at that time, goto step 1 that will pass successfully (because the queue will be empty at that time)
   c - cancel form submission (the queue is not currently empty)

Some code with comments :

```
    // Client side form validation
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        var myForm = e.currentTarget;
        var uploader = $(item).pluploadQueue();

        // if files in queue upload them first. Cancel current form submission.
        // Subscribe to 'StateChanged' to check if the queue is empty and try 
        // a new submission, each time a file is finished uploading

        if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
            // When all files are uploaded submit form
            uploader.bind('StateChanged', function() {
                if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                    myForm.submit(); // 
                }
            });
           // start uploading remaining files. 
           // End of each upload will trigger the 'StateChanged'
            uploader.start(); 
           // there are files in queue. (the reason we are running current block)
           // Cancel current form submission 
            return false;  
        }
        return true; // the queue is empty, validate current form submission
    });
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for your example, I already created a working example but it's just that I noticed the difference in form calls and I wonder why my second example doesn't cause a loop like my first example, because you still have one form on the page?